# Delete Element from the Page

Tags: javascript, html

the teacher asked us to design a website to teach children letters, when I click the generate button, it generates letters in a random way, and when I click on a letter, an image of something that starts with this letter is displayed. The problem is when I click on another letter, it displays an image of something that starts with this letter, but The old image of the other letter is still present on the page and is not deleted. What I want is when I click on a letter it displays an image of something that begins with this letter and when I click on another letter I want it to delete the old image and display only the image that begins with this letter
this is my JS code

```
var div2 = document.getElementById("div2");
var div3 = document.getElementById("div3");
var generate = document.getElementById("generate");
var input = document.getElementById("input"); 
var letters = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'];
// here to add the path of the each img to array to store it becuase we will need it leter 
litterImg = [];
for (let i = 0;i < 26;i++) {
    litterImg[i] = 'img\\'+i+'.jpg';
};
var randomLetter = [];
var getRandomLetter = [];
var linkImg = [];
var numberOfLitters;
generate.addEventListener("click",function(e){ 
    numberOfLitters = input.valueAsNumber;
    for (let index = 0; index < numberOfLitters; index++) { 
        let x = randomNumbers();
        randomLetter[index]  = document.createElement("input");
        randomLetter[index].setAttribute("type","button");
        randomLetter[index].setAttribute("value",letters[x]);
        randomLetter[index].setAttribute("id", x);
        randomLetter[index].setAttribute("class",x);
        div2.appendChild(randomLetter[index]);
    }});
// event to add the images when i click on a litter  
div2.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    for (let index = 0; index < 26; index++) {
        if (e.target.id == index) {
            linkImg[index] = document.createElement("img");
            linkImg[index].setAttribute("src",litterImg[index]);
            linkImg[index].setAttribute("width","1080px");
            linkImg[index].setAttribute("height","720px");
            div3.appendChild(linkImg[index]);
        }
    }
});
```

and this is my html code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta>
        <title>Alphabet Learner</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="div" class="div"  style="text-align : center;">
            <h1>Learn the English Litters </h1><br>
            <label >Number of Litters: </label>
            <input type="number" class="input" id="input" >
            <input type="button" class="generate" id="generate" value="Generate">
            <br><br>
            <div id="div2" class="div2">
            </div><br>
            <div id="div3" class="div3"></div>
        </div>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the script a bit more than it was needed, sorry for that. Anyway, it works!
The main part was to add the removal of element before the addition of a new one.

```js
const generate = document.getElementById("generate");
const input = document.getElementById("input");
const div2 = document.getElementById("div2");
const div3 = document.getElementById("div3");

const letters = [
  "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M",
  "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"
];

// here to add the path of the each img to array to store it becuase we will need it leter
const letterImg = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
  letterImg[i] = "img\\" + i + ".jpg";
}

generate.addEventListener("click", function () {
  const numberOfLetters = input.valueAsNumber;
  for (let i = 0; i < numberOfLetters; i++) {
    const x = randomNumber();
    const randomLetter = document.createElement("input");
    randomLetter.setAttribute("type", "button");
    randomLetter.setAttribute("value", letters[x]);
    randomLetter.setAttribute("id", x);
    randomLetter.setAttribute("class", x);
    div2.appendChild(randomLetter);
  }
});

function randomNumber() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 26);
}

// event to add the images when i click on a litter
div2.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  const index = e.target.id;
  const linkImg = document.createElement("img");
  linkImg.setAttribute("src", letterImg[index]);
  linkImg.setAttribute("width", "1080px");
  linkImg.setAttribute("height", "720px");
  
  // remove old image
  const old = document.querySelector('#div3 img');
  old && old.remove();
  // add new image
  div3.appendChild(linkImg);
});
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="div" class="div" style="text-align: center;">
    <h1>Learn the English Letters </h1><br>
    <label>Number of Letters: </label>
    <input type="number" class="input" id="input">
    <input type="button" class="generate" id="generate" value="Generate">
    <br><br>
    <div id="div2" class="div2"></div>
    <br>
    <div id="div3" class="div3"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```